# How do I know all the events (especially webkit only) supported by webkit/chrome/safari

Tags: javascript, webkit

I just cannot find a reference doc for webkit/chrome/safari

Comment: Try these links - [Safari DOM Extension](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariJSRef/index.html ) - [Event Compatibility Tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html )